QField and PostGIS on iOS
I have no issues with setting up a QField project with PostGIS layer on Android. However, I can't do it with for an iPhone, even though I've put the pg_service.conf file on QField root and auth folders.
Anyone with experience on this?

I don't use Apple, but documentation states:


On Linux/MacOS/Unix: Create a file named .pg_service.conf in your home folder (~).


